# It is necessary to normalise the table in order?

Tags: database, database-normalization

It is necessary to normalize table in order like first we have to convert in `1NF` then `2NF` then `3NF` and so on.. or we can skip any.
Ex-

```
R(ABCDE)
AB->C,C->D,B->E
It is in only 1NF not in 2NF bcoz C->D is Partial dependency.
so first i have to convert it into 2NF then 3NF (by rule i thnk so)
but i can convert directly it in 3NF without 2NF
For 3NF :
AB->C is correct.
C->D & B->E not correct.
so  i can make NEW tables  
R(ABC),R(CD),R(BE) [candidate keys are AB,C,B in respective tables)
AB->C ,C->D,B->E is correct so it is in 3NF
```

So it necessary to follow order or not.

Comment: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Answer (score 2):

Some lower normal forms don't apply.  Sometimes a relation is already in 3NF before you do anything to it.  You can skip normal forms that don't apply and you can jump straight to 3NF (or higher, if applicable) directly.  **It is not necessary to do each step before proceeding to the next.**

Comment: While I agree very much that sequence is not important, verifying the normalization of at least 1, 2 and 3 is necessary and should not be skipped.

Comment: @symcbean - It is probably a matter of semantics, but a relation that is in 3NF is by definition already in 1NF and 2NF.  If your preferred process is to look for the markers of 0NF, 1NF, 2NF etc. in that order, then that is a good, systematic process, but it isn't necessary to follow that process in order, which is what the OP was asking.